# What does setattr function do in this threading code

Tags: python, multithreading

I am learning a piece of code as follows:

```
class TestApp(TestWrapper, TestClient):
    def __init__(self, ipaddress, portid, clientid):
    TestWrapper.__init__(self)
    TestClient.__init__(self, wrapper=self)

    self.connect(ipaddress, portid, clientid)

    thread = Thread(target = self.run)
    thread.start()

    setattr(self, "_thread", thread)

    self.init_error()
```

I am interested in its threading component, I do not understand what setattr does here, can someone please explain?

Many thanks

Comment: It's equivalent to `self._thread = thread`. Have you read the `setattr` documentation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using setattr() in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561174/using-setattr-in-python)

Comment: Yes, I get that, but I don't why we set an attribute like that.

Comment: We can't possibly know why _your_ code sets that attribute. We don't know anything about the `TestApp` class _or_ the `TestWrapper` class _or_ the `TestClient` class. So my best guess is: You're setting the attribute because you want to access it later.

Answer (score 0):

```
setattr(object, name, value)
```

The function assigns the value to the attribute of the provided object. For example: `setattr(objectA, 'attr', 'foo')` is equivalent to `x.foobar = 'foo'`.

In your code:
`setattr(self, "_thread", thread)` is equivalent to `self._thread=thread`.

For more information you could visit [python_setattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr)

I hope this help you!

Comment: Thanks. I get that, but I still dont know why we set an attribute _thread equals thread?