# Defining attribute with variable name

Tags: python, class, attributes

This works:

```
self.NN0d = [(0, 1, np.array([0, -1]))]
```

This does not work:

```
name = str("NN{}d".format(0))
self.name = [(0, 1, np.array([0, -1]))]
```

I'm not sure why exactly...

Ultimately, I would like to define multiple class attributes in a loop, like so:

```
for i in range(0, 14, 2):
    name = str("NN{}d".format(i))
    self.name = [(i, i+1, np.array([0, -1]))]
```

Comment: `NN0d` is not a string, while your `name` is a string `"NN0d"`. Try `setattr` and `getattr` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9561207/11516012

Comment: Thank you! I think this answers my question:

        for i in range(0, 14, 2):
            setattr(self, "NN{}d".format(i), [(i, i+1, np.array([0, -1]))])