# Populate class attributes with __init__ arguments automatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I have a class that can be initialized with a lot of argument and it can keep growing as a add methods. Is there a way to add all the positional arguments in **int** method to the object's properties authomatically? For example;

```
class trainer:
    
    def __int__(self, model="unet", encoder_name="resnet18", encoder_weights="imagenet",
              in_channels=3, num_classes=1, loss="jaccard",
              ignore_index=0, learning_rate=1e4, learning_rate_schedule_patience=10,
              ignore_zeros=True):

        # authomatically add the initial properties
        self.model = model
        self.encoder_name = encoder_name
        self.encoder_weights = encoder_weights
        self.in_channels = in_channels
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        .
        .
        .
        self.ignore_zeros = ignore_zeros
```

Comment: That’s basically what a `dataclass` is for.

Comment: Note, there is typo. It is `__init__`, not `__int__`.  You can use `setattr()` in a loop. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561174/using-setattr-in-python

Answer (score 1):

This is the corresponding [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) to your `__init__`.

Basically you just declare a class with annotated attributes and possibly a default value, the `@dataclass` decorator will generate boilerplate code for you like `__init__` or `__repr__`, I recommend you read more of their [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)

**PS.** [class names are normally PascalCase (or CapWords)](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#class-names), so I made that change for you.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Trainer:
    model: str = "unet"
    encoder_name: str = "resnet18"
    encoder_weights: str = "imagenet"
    in_channels: int = 3
    num_classes: int = 1
    loss: str = "jaccard"
    ignore_index: int = 0
    learning_rate: float = 1e4
    learning_rate_schedule_patience: int = 10
    ignore_zeros: bool = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this by looping through the parameters that are passed to the `__init__` and then using `setattr` to `self` to save the variables.

The advantage here is that it defaults to your default kwargs but updates to any input kwargs (which in this example is `num_classes`) -

```
class trainer():
    
    def __init__(self, model="unet", encoder_name="resnet18", encoder_weights="imagenet",
              in_channels=3, num_classes=1, loss="jaccard",
              ignore_index=0, learning_rate=1e4, learning_rate_schedule_patience=10,
              ignore_zeros=True):
        
        # Loop through params and setattr v to self.k
        for k,v in locals().items():
            if k!='self':
                setattr(self, k, v)
                
#checking the self dictionary                
trainer(num_classes=10).__dict__
```

```
{'model': 'unet',
 'encoder_name': 'resnet18',
 'encoder_weights': 'imagenet',
 'in_channels': 3,
 'num_classes': 10,               #<--------------
 'loss': 'jaccard',
 'ignore_index': 0,
 'learning_rate': 10000.0,
 'learning_rate_schedule_patience': 10,
 'ignore_zeros': True}
```

Comment: interacting with locals is a terrible idea unless there is a good reason.  I would suggest ljmc answer above.